# Error in if not exists query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc

What is wrong with this following query? I can't find the error. Can anyone help
me with this issue?

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
               FROM chennai_metro_data 
               WHERE TIME1 ='09:00' AND DATE1 ='1-23-2017')) 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO chennai_metro_data 
    VALUES (2021700002,'1-23-2017','09:00',1,0,555555) 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE chennai_metro_data 
    SET CUMFLOW = 555555 
    WHERE TIME1 = '09:00' AND DATE1 = '1-23-2017' 
END
```

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Comment: As a best practice, you should **always** define the **list of columns** you're inserting into when using `INSERT` ..... that helps avoid a lot of problems !

Comment: Also, for string representation of date data types, use either yyyy-mm-dd or yyyymmdd.

Comment: @marc_s it works!! Thank you. As per your advice, I have added list of columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a best practice, you should always define the list of columns you're inserting into when using `INSERT` - that helps avoid a lot of problems !

And also: for the dates, to be independent of any language & regional settings, try to use the ISO-8601 format - `YYYYMDDD` for just dates (no time), or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for date & time.

So try this code:

```
INSERT INTO chennai_metro_data(col1, col2, ...., colN)
VALUES (2021700002, '20170123', '09:00', 1, 0, 555555)
```

and replace `col1` thorugh `colN` with your **actual column names** from that table that you want to insert data into.

Comment: JUst adding, when you have adat mismatch error in an insert without the columns listed, it almost certainly mans the columns in the insert are not in the same order as the columns in the table. This is one reason why it is critical to always add the column list. Also, sometimes people actually change the column order in tables. They shouldn't (because then stuff breaks) but they do.